# iPhone download / parse xml file on app launch?

Tags: iphone, xml, background, download

I'm working on a storyboard app in which one of it's tabbed views is a mapView that downloads points from an xml file on a server. Everytime the app is launched and that tab in the tab bar controller is selected, it takes a second to download the file and parse it. Worse still, if there is no access to internet, the app crashes :/

I would like to try to use my getDataService (which downloads and parses) during the splash screen of the app instead of on ViewDidLoad of the viewcontroller (is this in appdelegate under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?) and let it do its thing then, or in the background, and keep working in the background if the app is closed.

Then I'd like the array to be retained for future use (does this have to do with dictionaries?) and only re-download and parse the xml when the app is fully restarted.

How can I do these things? If anyone has examples or links to tutorials and examples that do these things, I'd be very grateful. I've been searching for a while, but I don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually DO NOT do this during didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

The reason is that iOS will kill any application that takes too long to load. I don't have the relevant documentation to hand, but iOS expects your app to finish launching within a specific period of time (I believe it's around 3 seconds or so) and if this method is not finished within that time frame you app is deemed to have hung and iOS will kill it.

The recommended technique is that if you have long running code is to start a background thread with the code on it.

The whole idea is to get the user to a usable interface as quickly as possible. Note that the debugger disables iOS's kill function, it's only active when your code is on a device and no you cannot disable it programmatically. So your code will appear to be fine when developing but fail when you run it for real.

If you need to display something whilst loading, I'd recommend putting the long running code on a background thread and continuing on to a temporary view which is basically a copy of the splash screen. then when you data is available, load up your interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this from the AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLoading function, and assign it to a property that you define for you AppDelegate, your loading screen will still be visible while your data is being downloaded and parsed.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplicatioN *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSLog(@"loading!");
    sleep(5); //delay to show you that the log happens before the loading screen goes away
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the first screen that shows when the app launches (after the `Default.png` splash screen) be the same or a very similar image, but give the user feedback that something is happening -- e.g. a `UIActivityIndicator`.

If your app doesn't fail gracefully when launched with no internet connection, Apple will reject it. Show a relevant message in this situation which advises the user something like either of these:

1) No internet connection, so functionality of this app may be limited

2) No internet connection, and this app will not function with it